# Share a as3 class between domains

Tags: actionscript-3, security, dns, sandbox, applicationdomain

I have a Singleton class instantiated in **Main.swf** located at **domainA**. The file loads **Game.swf** from **domainB** via **LoaderMax** (http://www.greensock.com/). When I try to access the Singleton I guess this is not the same as the on instatiated in **Main.swf**.

Is there any way of forcing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the same singleton if your files are loaded into the same application domain.  You can use [LoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) to do that.

Also, you can use a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) framework, like [SwiftSuspenders](http://www.tillschneidereit.de/2009/09/21/introducing-swiftsuspenders/), to take care of this more elegantly, but since most of these rely heavily on [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29), I would advise to test for performance issues if you need to inject stuff into a lot of game objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many problems with using Singleton (http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/). Might I suggest that, instead, you simply pass the instance into the game.swf, and leave the responsibility of how that is instantiated to main.swf?